# Can't properly append JS obj values into dynamically-created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, methods

I have some categories that are coming in via axios and each one has a description. Each category title is housed in its own div that was cloned using templates---for instance, clicking on the div that says "Animals" opens a modal and the title "Animals" also shows up. I can see each of the descriptions in the console but I've been unable to append the right description into the right modal.

For now, I have it so that modal shows the same description (which is the last value), and I'm not sure why. If I move the `$.each` outside of the loop it's the same thing.

Earlier on I tried setting attributes in order to get the descriptions to load properly, but it only seemed to work with the category titles.

Any thoughts? How can I append the correct description value into the correct div?

#### [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbekn3m4/1/)

#### JS snippet:

```
loadCategories(){
        // debugger;
        let categs = _categories,
        libCrs = _library

        console.log(typeof categs); // obj

            let $host = $("#host");
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                let $template = $("#template").clone();

                $("#cat-title").empty();
                $("#cat-title").append(categs[i].Title);

                $("#cat-box-id").attr("data-category", categs[i].Title); // keep

                $host.append($template.html());
                console.log('catdesc ' + categs[i].Description) // does show everything (see console snippet below)

                $.each(categs, function(i, val) {
                    $("#category-desc").empty();
                    $("#category-desc").append(val.Description);
                })
            }

            let container = document.querySelector("div#template");
            container.innerHTML = $host;

    }
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="template" style="display:none">
            <div class="cat-box" id="cat-box-id" data-target="#modal-id" data-toggle="modal">
                <h3 class="cat-title" id="cat-title"></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="category-desc" id="category-desc"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

#### console:

```
catdesc Animals are multicellular eukaryotic organisms 
// five others
catdesc A capital city (or simply capital) is the municipality exercising primary // this is what's being appended into every div
```

Comment: Think you're going to have to knock up a jsfiddle mate...

Comment: Hi @An0nC0d3r here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbekn3m4/1/). I modified it so that the Category Descriptions are local instead of rendered via axios.

Comment: I just see a search bar that you can't interact with?